# Move a directory and its contents up several levels

Tags: linux, command-line, unix

I have a directory with text files in `/user/data/tutorial/texts/` and I'd like to move the (sub)directory `Folder2/` with all of its contents to `/user/`.

How should I go about this using unix commands?

Answer (score 3):

The `mv` command moves files and directories between directories.

Assuming that you have write access to both `/user` (for creating new files and directories therein) and `/user/data/tutorial/texts` (for deleting the directory `Folder2`), then the following command will do what you ask for:

```
mv /user/data/tutorial/texts/Folder2 /user
```